# Do something if option is None or value satisfies condition

Tags: scala

If I have an `Option[Int]` and a function `validateInt(i: Int): Boolean`. I want to do something if the option is empty or if it passes the validation.

I know it can be done with

```
if (opt.forall(validateInt)) {
   // do something
}
```

Is there a more functionally idiomatic way to do this in Scala?

Comment: Your code is functional and idiomatic.

Comment: @OlegPyzhcov The if statement is bugging me^^. Maybe I'm just code golfing too much

Comment: @uraza A bare `if` without an `else` implies non-functional code, so perhaps that is what is worrying you? (And for the purists, yes I know that this is not always true)

Comment: @Tim same can be said about any function returning `Unit` (since it implies side effects). Like `.foreach` :)

Answer (score 4):

`opt.filterNot(validateInt).getOrElse(doStuff): Unit`

But really, this does not look any better to my eye than your `if` statement.